# Android Build in docker container

Tags: android, docker, gradle, aapt2

I try to run android build on docker container.

My dockerfile's contents is here:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /myapp
WORKDIR /myapp
COPY . .

RUN apk add --update nodejs nodejs-npm
RUN apk add git
RUN apk add zip
RUN apk --no-cache add curl
```

I create a docker image and run it. I run below commands on docker terminal.

```
wget https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-4333796.zip
unzip -q sdk-tools-linux-4333796.zip -d Android-sdk
export ANDROID_HOME=/path-to-sdk/Android-sdk
export PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/tools:${ANDROID_HOME}/tools/bin:${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools
yes | sdkmanager  --licenses
cd MyApplication && chmod +x gradlew && ./gradlew :app:assembledebug
```

MyApplication is a default empty activity project of Android Studio.

Error log is here:

> /gradlew :app:assembledebug
>
> > Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> >     Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> >     Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> >     Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
> >     Task :app:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> >     Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> >     Task :app:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
> >     Task :app:mainApkListPersistenceDebug UP-TO-DATE
> >     Task :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> >     Task :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> >     Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>
>   > java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2
>   >     aapt2-3.3.0-alpha12-5013011-linux Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
>   >     This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an
>   >     issue if it does.
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

**EDIT**

This project works fine on my mac laptop. Local machine build is ok but it doesn't work on docker container.

**EDIT**

I run `--stacktrace` parameter. aapt2 not found

> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program
>   "/root/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-linux.jar/6f8af69a2b8f839763b018ee3b5c1d41/aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-linux/aapt2":
>   error=2, No such file or directory
>           at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonImpl.startProcess(Aapt2DaemonImpl.kt:80)
>           at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Daemon.checkStarted(Aapt2Daemon.kt:53)
>           ... 8 more Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
>           ... 10 more

Comment: Hey there, did you find a good solution to this?
I am having a silimar issue ("NO-SOURCE") when trying to compile an Android app on a debian buster container.
Locally, it runs smooth, however in docker...

Comment: Inside my task, I ran a script which did not execute correctly. So, in the logs gradle was complaining about NO-SOURCE, but the script actually failed, which uses the appcenter cli and something went wrong with the authentication. 
As said, on the development machine it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Faced the same issue in `openjdk:8-jre-alpine` docker image.

The issue was resolved when I used `oracle/openjdk:8` as the base image

Change your Dockerfile like this and try again:

```
FROM oracle/openjdk:8
RUN mkdir -p /myapp
WORKDIR /myapp
COPY . .

RUN yum install -y nodejs nodejs-npm
RUN yum install -y git zip curl
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, very useful and straightforward.
it comes with appium and latest SDK, also has a feature to open emulator in headed mode

https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/amrka/ultimate-android

Comment: Github repo for this docker image appears to be https://github.com/amrsa1/Android-Emulator-Docker . However it doesn't show the Dockerfile of the base image, so it is unclear how it was created. It'd be good if the Dockerfile was added to the repo, so people can decide whether or not to use it.

Comment: Sorry, will not use an image without source. Also it says "The image is updated regulary every month", but as of now it's not been updated in three months.